# How to exclude referenced Firebase modules in TypeScript Compiler - tsc?

Tags: typescript, firebase, typescript2.0, tsc

I have config

```
"exclude": [
"node_modules",
"functions/node_modules",
"typings/browser.d.ts",
"typings/browser"
]
```

and imports;

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
import DateUtilities from "../Utilities/DateUtilities";
import CoreUtilities from "../Utilities/CoreUtilities";
```

and method like;

```
async GetDocumentData(id: string): Promise<DocumentData> {
let snapshot = await this.GetDocumentSnapshot(id);
return await snapshot.data();
}
```

`DocumentData` is a module comes from `firebase-admin`.
Normally if I don't use it in `GetDocumentData` return value `tsc` does not try to compile it.

But once I start to use it, it tries to validate all referenced modules like below:

[image: [image]]

How can I force exclude them?

Answer (score 2):

After some search I found out I had to use `tsc --skipLibCheck`

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14293

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html